# Filtering from advance custom field data

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I want to achieve a schedule plan in my front-end. I cannot view information based on the Day. For example in the backend, a row is for Tuesday but its rendering on the column of monday in the front-end. I want it as, so entry for every day goes to its corresponding column and corresponding time. Please see the snapshots and my code below.

Front-End
[image: Front-End]

Back-End
[image: Back-End]

```
<div class="table-responsive">
 <table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>MONTAG</td>
          <td>DIENSTAG</td>
          <td>MITTWOCH</td>
          <td>DONNERSTAG</td>
          <td>FREITAG</td>
          <td>SAMSTAG</td>
          <td>SONNTAG</td>
      </tr>
  </thead>



  <?php while(have_rows('tag')) :the_row();  ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo get_sub_field('uhrzeit'); ?></td>   
        <td>
              <?php $aufguss_object = get_sub_field('aufguss');?>
              <?php $sauna_object = get_sub_field('sauna');?>

              <?php if($aufguss_object) { ?>
                  <?php $post = $aufguss_object; ?>
                  <?php setup_postdata( $post );  ?>
                  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></br>
                  <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
              <?php } ?>

              <?php if($sauna_object) { ?>
                  <?php $post = $sauna_object; ?>
                  <?php setup_postdata( $post );  ?>
                  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></br>
                  <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
              <?php } ?>
        </td>        

      </tr> 
      <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little more complicated. You have to loop through the elements first, and create a twodimensional array containing weekday and time.

```
$entries = array();
while ( have_rows('tag') ) : the_row();

    //clean thisentry
    $thisentry = array();

    // set aufguss and sauno for thisentry
    $thisentry['aufguss'] = get_sub_field('aufguss');
    $thisentry['sauna'] = get_sub_field('sauna');

    // populate array for wochentag/uhrzeit
    $entries[get_sub_field('wochentag')][get_sub_field('uhrzeit')] = $thisentry;

endwhile;
```

Now you can define your Weekdays and times, like:

```
$wochentage = array( 'Montag', 'Dienstag', 'Mittwoch', 'Donnerstag', 'freitag', 'Samstag', 'Sonntag' );
$uhrzeiten = array( '11:00', '11:30', '12:00', '12:30' );
```

And start building up the table, making a nested loop through times and days. I loop through the times first, so I can build the lines of my table.

For example, my time has the value `11:00`, and I loop through all the days, and add the entry of each day for the time `11:00` to a new line of the table.

For each time I create an additional cell with the time itself, and for each day I add another cell to my first line, so I get the complete table, and add this together to create a full table. Echo it and voila :)

The whole commented code:

```
$entries = array();
while ( have_rows('tag') ) : the_row();

    //clean thisentry
    $thisentry = array();

    // set aufguss and sauno for thisentry
    $thisentry['aufguss'] = get_sub_field('aufguss');
    $thisentry['sauna'] = get_sub_field('sauna');

    // populate array for wochentag/uhrzeit
    $entries[get_sub_field('wochentag')][get_sub_field('uhrzeit')] = $thisentry;

endwhile;

$wochentage = array( 'Montag', 'Dienstag', 'Mittwoch', 'Donnerstag', 'freitag', 'Samstag', 'Sonntag' );
$uhrzeiten = array( '11:00', '11:30', '12:00', '12:30' );

//create first cell of heading line
$thead.= '<tr><td>&nbsp</td>';

// loop through each line of the output
foreach( $uhrzeiten as $uhrzeit ) {

    // create new line with first cell of time
    $lines.= '<tr><td>' . $uhrzeit . '</td>';

    // loop through each day
    foreach( $wochentage as $wochentag ) {

        //create day cell of heading line
        $thead.= '<td>' . $wochentag . '</td>';

        //create the elements
        $aufguss = "";
        $sauna = "";
        if( $entries[$wochentag][$uhrzeit]['aufguss'] ) {
            $thisaufguss = get_post( $entries[$wochentag][$uhrzeit]['aufguss'] );
            $aufguss = '<a href="' . get_permalink( $thisaufguss->ID ) . '">' . $thisaufguss->post_title . '</a><br />';
        }
        if( $entries[$wochentag][$uhrzeit]['sauna'] ) {
            $thissauna = get_post( $entries[$wochentag][$uhrzeit]['sauna'] );
            $sauna = '<a href="' . get_permalink( $thissauna->ID ) . '">' . $thissauna->post_title . '</a><br />';
        }
        // add the entry to the lines
        $lines.= '<td>' . $aufguss . $sauna . '</td>';

    }

    //close the line
    $lines.= '</tr>';

}

//close heading line
$thead.= '</tr>';

//create the table
$table = '<table>' . $thead . $lines . '</table>';

echo $table;
```

Comment: Hey fischi..thanks for your quick reply man...i will try your solution tomorrow morning and get back to you...thanks a lot man..

Comment: Hello fischi, I used your code exactly as it is...but now its printing out each wochentag name 4 times as its looping over the the time array..and it cannot extract post_title from the sauna and aufguss object...see the link please: http://imgur.com/lZOR8kS

Comment: OK,I solved the wochentag problem...this line ($thead.= '<td>' . $wochentag . '</td>';)  should be out of uhrzeit loop...but i still cannot extract the post_title from sauna and aufguss objects...please help me out

Comment: hey fischi, i solved that too..it was my wochentag key which was making the problem...thanks for your wonderful and excellent solution...thanks a lot man...great work....cheers

Comment: No problem, just wanted to update the answer. The problem is the wochentag was added to the `$thead` each time, when it should only be added once. Glad you figured it out :)

Comment: yeah you are right man...thanks again a bunch for this perfect solution...take care